# How to find Startdate - Enddate in userform, and search in all columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am new here and this is my first post. I am new in excel vba and i am asking your help.

I have a file that has a searchform. I want help in 2 items:

In `Sheets("Production")` i have data in `Columns A-J`.
The 1st Column is a date and I want to make an option to choose `StartDate` and `EndDate` of search in the form.
For example I have in the sheet dates from `01/01/2014` until `08/02/2014` and I want to choose `StartDate` and `EndDate` between them.

The other one is the search of words in the `Textbox`. Now it is only on `Column A` and I want it to be on all the used `Columns`.
But when I change in the code to all the `Columns A-L` it is showing me in the listbox only data from the `Cell` to the end and not from `Column A` to the end.
Thanks in advance.

**Here's the code:**

```
Private Sub TitleBox_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ListBox.Clear
    Locate TitleBox.Text, Worksheets("production").Range("a:a")
    If ListBox.ListCount = 0 Then
        ListBox.AddItem "-"
        ListBox.List(0, 1) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 2) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 3) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 4) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 5) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 6) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 7) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 8) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 9) = ""
    End If
End Sub

Sub Locate(Name As String, Data As Range)
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Dim strFirstFind As String

    On Error Resume Next

    With Data
        Set rngFind = .Find(Name, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            strFirstFind = rngFind.Address
            Do
                If rngFind.Row > 1 Then
                    ListBox.AddItem rngFind.Value
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 0) = rngFind.Cells(1, "a")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 1) = rngFind.Cells(1, "b")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 2) = rngFind.Cells(1, "c")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 3) = rngFind.Cells(1, "d")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 4) = rngFind.Cells(1, "e")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 5) = rngFind.Cells(1, "f")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 6) = rngFind.Cells(1, "g")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 7) = rngFind.Cells(1, "h")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 8) = rngFind.Cells(1, "i")
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 9) = rngFind.Cells(1, "j")
                End If
            Set rngFind = .FindNext(rngFind)
            Loop While Not rngFind Is Nothing And rngFind.Address <> strFirstFind
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox12.Text = Sheets("main").Range("L2").Text
    TextBox12.Value = Format(TextBox12.Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    TextBox13.Text = Sheets("main").Range("L3").Text
    TextBox13.Value = Format(TextBox13.Value, "mm-dd-yy")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

**Code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()        
    TextBox12.Value = Format(Sheets("main").Range("L2").Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    TextBox13.Value = Format(Sheets("main").Range("L3").Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")
End Sub

Private Sub MenuButton_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Sub Locate(Name As String, Data As Range)
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Dim strFirstFind As String

    With Data
        Set rngFind = .Find(Name, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart)
        If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
            strFirstFind = rngFind.Address
            Do
                If rngFind.Row > 1 Then
                    ListBox.AddItem .Cells(rngFind.Row, 1)
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 2) = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 2)
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 3) = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 3)
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 4) = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 4)
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 5) = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 5)
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 6) = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 6)
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 7) = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 7)
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 8) = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 8)
                    ListBox.List(ListBox.ListCount - 1, 9) = .Cells(rngFind.Row, 9)                     
                End If
                Set rngFind = .FindNext(rngFind)
            Loop While Not rngFind Is Nothing And rngFind.Address <> strFirstFind
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub TitleBox_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ListBox.Clear

    Locate TitleBox.Text, Worksheets("production").Range("a:j")

    If ListBox.ListCount = 0 Then
        ListBox.AddItem "-"
        ListBox.List(0, 1) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 2) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 3) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 4) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 5) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 6) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 7) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 8) = ""
        ListBox.List(0, 9) = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

Comment: yes i made and no changes. i want 2 things. first that search will be from startdate and enddate. and not like now on all data

Comment: Can you upload a sample workbook in say www.wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: and the other is that i want the search that will be on all columns and not only on "a"

Comment: You have cross posted it in another forum as well? :D This is not the right thing to do. You may want to see [THIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f29e7344-f683-43b3-97fb-7cbc6bc6f4b0/name-vs-namelocal-vba?forum=exceldev)

Comment: Looking at your file now.

Comment: It's not about enrolling in other forums. It's about posting the same question multiple times at multiple forums See the link I gave in the last comment

Comment: I understand now. I will not do it again

Comment: Ok what you you want to search in the text box?

Comment: Each letter or word within columns A-J

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: yes. if i write "4" or "w" or "2014" or "ta1" that he will give me all the row from a to j

Comment: I do not have specific letter! Simple letter or word I want to choose

Comment: its can be every word or number

Comment: Ok gimme 30 mins. need to run some errand and then i will work on the file. the logic has to be changed slightly

Comment: Ah I see the problem :) Updating the post

Comment: can u help me with the other problem? i want to have the posebility to ad range of dates insted of all the data. startdate and enddate in textbox 12 and 13

Comment: for that you will have to create a similar change event for the other 2 textboxes and this time you will search only column A and Col C respectively